# focusout event on div not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following jQuery code:

```
$("#contact-form-applet").on("focusout",".dc2-ltfc", {ctx:this},function(event) {
    var curRowDiv = $(this);
    var rowObject = {};
    curRowDiv.find("input, textarea").each(function(e){
        rowObject[ $(this).attr("aria-label") ] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(rowObject);
});
```

The issue is that code is triggered every time a field loses a focus (field tab out) rather than complete div losing the focus.

Here is the [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ngautam/zW43H/1/) demonstrating the problem.

I would like to trigger the code only when a particular row div losses focus, so that I can trigger update once and not every time a field in a row is updated.

Comment: Probably I think you should combine both focusout and focusin, to acheive your objective. On focusin of the next row trigger update for the previous row.

Comment: This will fail if users never goes to the second row and also last row would be skipped as there will not be any focus in event.

Comment: Then i think you should probably target the last input field of a row. :)

Comment: nothing is mandatory and there is no possibility that user will focus on each and every input field. So, cannot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) says this:

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it, loses focus.

Hence, `focusout` event will fire each time when any of the child element loses its focus. Alternatively, you can use `body`'s `keyup` and `click` event to solve this by checking `closest` element like this:

```
    var previousId=null;

    $('body').keyup(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (code == '9') {
            focusChange(e);
        }

    });

    $('body').click(function (e) {
        focusChange(e);
    });

    function focusChange(e) {
        if (!previousId) {
            previousId = $(e.target).closest('.dc2-ltfcc').attr('id');
            return;
        }
        if (previousId != $(e.target).closest('.dc2-ltfcc').attr('id')) {
            console.log('Exit');
            previousId = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/knvn/mKCU4/1/) demonstrating the solution.

Comment: So, there is no event in jQuery that can help me achieve the requirement?

Comment: Seems not, because `div` is not a `forms` element and hence `blur` is not supported.

Comment: Accepting as an answer as it gives the desired result but I was not able to use it due to several restrictions in our application.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but someone else may find it useful. My solution is somewhat hackish, but it is deterministic. It relies on how the JS engine schedules async processes on its single execution thread. The solution is in Angular for multiple rows of data, where I want to know if the user accessed a different field in the same row (don't trigger save) or left the row for a different row or anywhere else (trigger save). The div's (rows) are identified with the row index, but you can use any label for identifying the div depending on your use case.

Add the focusin and focusout event handlers to the div (displaying a row of data):

```
<div class="hover-row row"
    *ngFor="let lineItem of line_items; let i = index"
    (focusout)="onFocusOut(i)" (focusin)="onFocusIn(i)">
```

Then create these event handler functions:

```
  onFocusOut(index) {
    console.log('row focus out');
    this.newAccessedIndex = -1; 
    setTimeout(() => this.saveLineItem(index), 0);
  }

  onFocusIn(index) {
    console.log('row focus in');
    this.newAccessedIndex = index;
  }

  saveLineItem(index) {
    if (index == this.newAccessedIndex) {
      console.log('stayed within row -> no save');
    } else {
      console.log('left row -> save');
    }
  }
```

The idea is that when leaving an input field in the row, focusout is triggered on the div. If a different input field is accessed in the same row, focusin is triggered for the div. In focusout we reset the index (label) of the last accessed row, in focusin we set the index. In focusout saveLineItem is called on a different execution thread, so when accessing tabbing in one row from one input field to the other, we get these console logs:

```
row focus out
row focus in
stayed within row -> no save
```